# React, can't set up auto update on emit change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my component class (Part of it).

```
updateStore: function() {
  console.log("Updating state in the Calendar.js");
  this.setState(this.getInitialState());
},

componentDidMount: function() {
  EventsStore.addChangeListener(this.updateStore, 'CHANGE');
},

componentDidUnmount: function() {
  EventStore.removeChangeListener(this.updateStore);
},
```

This is my action (Tuxx)

```
var Actions = require('tuxx/Actions');
var eventsStore = require('../Stores/EventsStore');
var jQ = require('jquery');

var eventsActions = Actions.createActionCategory({
  category: 'events',
  source: 'standard',
  actions: ['create', 'get']
});

eventsActions.register(eventsStore, {
  create: eventsStore.onCreate,
   get: eventsStore.onGet
});

eventsActions.before('get', function (nextCallback, actionBody) {
  jQ.get('http://127.0.0.1:8181/events').done(function(resp) {
    nextCallback(resp);
  });
});

module.exports = eventsActions;
```

And this is part of my store

```
onGet: function(resp) {
    resp = JSON.parse(resp);
    this._events = resp;

    console.log(this._events);
    console.log("Emiting change")
    this.emitChange('CHANGE');
},
```

And last, this is my init code:

```
eventsAction.get();

var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
            <RouteHandler />
        </div>
    )
  } 
});

var routes = (
  <Route name="app" path="/" handler={App}>
    <DefaultRoute handler={Calendar} />
    <Route name="event.edit" path="/event/:eventId" handler=    {EventEditForm} />
  </Route>
);

Router.run(routes, function(Handler) {
  React.render(<Handler />, document.getElementById("main"));
});
```

As far as I understand, it should re render my component when emitChange is run.

This is my console output:

[image: Console output]

I think it should hit the

```
    console.log("Updating state in the Calendar.js");
```

part, but it doesn't.

I am far from being competent in JS world, so I need help.

Thank you in advance.

This is how store is required:

```
var EventsStore = require('./Stores/EventsStore');
```

store is saved as follows:

[image: Store in FS]

Store is defined as:

```js
var Stores = require('tuxx/Stores')

var eventsStore = Stores.createStore({
    _events: [],

    getAll: function () {
        return Object.keys(this._events);
    },

(...)
(...)

   onGet: function(resp) {
      resp = JSON.parse(resp);
      this._events = resp;

      console.log(this._events);
      console.log("Emiting change")
      this.emitChange();
  },

  register: function () {
      return {
          events: {
              create: this.onCreate,
              get: this.onGet
          }
      };
  }
  });

  module.exports = eventsStore;
```

In the component I use it using EventsStore variable which was created from:

```
    var EventsStore = require('./Stores/EventsStore');
```

Second edit. 
I was still digging and I found out this:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  EventsStore.addChangeListener(this.updateStore);
  console.log('Calendar::componentDidMount');
  console.log(EventsStore.listeners());
  console.log('----')
},
```

And the result in the console is:

```
[Log] Calendar::componentDidMount (app.js, line 36083)
[Log] [] (app.js, line 36084)
```

Answer (score 1):

Having looked at the Tuxx source code, I believe that should work. You can also omit that second "CHANGE" parameter to `emitChange` and `addChangeListener` and it'll use a default. I assume it's the same instance of the store you're using everywhere?

Looking at Tuxx, they use the createOwnerClass and connectOwnerToStore combo to make all of this happen automatically - see the [initial guide](https://tuxedojs.org/#Features-and-Examples) on the homepage. Perhaps using that approach would help you track down the bug?

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I know I can omit the "CHANGE", but it was just my X attempt :) I thought maybe it was something wrong with it.
I am not using their Owner and Ownee class because I have my components written earlier.. and now I just wanted to add stores, actions etc. Just can't figure out why thing I provided isn't working ;/

Comment: Can you edit your answer with the way you're exporting and then subsequently requiring your store?